Children's movie where two girls chase a ball into the woods and they meet father time. Half live-action, half animation
Okay so, when I was a kid I watched this movie. It had to be in the late 1980s to early 1990s where two little girls are playing with a ball and the ball ends up in the woods. So the girls chase it and they end up lost in the woods. They start noticing strange things about the woods which are portrayed with animation. They meet an animated talking frog or something similar at one point.
Then they meet this crazy guy whom I have started calling "Father Time". I don't know what his name actually is in the movie, but he's an old man with a long beard and when the girls are trying to get out of the woods before time runs out it keeps switching between watching the girls try to get out of the woods and this father time character saying "bong, bong, bong" all menacingly over and over.
It's in color and in English but I cannot for the life of me remember what this movie is called.

You saw a dubbed version of Maria, Mirabela from 1981. It's about two girls who chase a ball and find a magical forest. They meet an animated frog, as well as Uncle Time (played by the film's writer and director), a bearded, crazy-looking man; near the end, they run away as he's mouthing chime sounds (Bong, Bong, Bong). It's pretty trippy. ;)
EDIT: I found you the English version. It was called The Magical Forest and is available on Amazon, but according to this page, it's a pretty bad dub. Here's the original trailer:



